# mod_rewrite rewriting files that exist even when it should not

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following .htaccess file, which is producing quite a strange behavior.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
AddCharset UTF-8 .css
AddCharset UTF-8 .js

AddType image/svg+xml svg

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Hunpony/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1 [R=301] # Remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^$ do.php?do=news [QSA] # Default page
RewriteRule ^([\wáéíóöőúüű.]+|-?\d+)(?:\/((?:[\wáéíóöőúüű]+|-?\d+)(?:\/(?:[\wáéíóöőúüű]+|-?\d+))?))?\/?$ do.php?do=$1&data=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /Hunpony/404
```

I thought those `RewriteCond`s would prevent Apache from performing a rewrite if the requested file exists, but this does not seem to be the case.

This file is placed in the `/Hunpony/` subfolder of my sever, alongside `do.php`, which handles page requests. This is an example how the redirect works: it redirects `/Hunpony/profile/1/setings` to `/Hunpony/do.php?do=profile&data=1/settings`. The catch is that I also want to allow dots in the first match, so `/Hunpony/f.a.q` would be redirected to `/Hunpony/do.php?do=f.a.q&data=`.

The problem I'm facing is that for some odd reason, the site's favicon (`/Hunpony/favicon.ico`) is returning a 404 error, despite the fact that it's linked where it's supposed to be.

The only possible explanation I can think of is that Apache rewrites `/Hunpony/favicon.ico` to `/Hunpony/do.php?do=favicon.ico&data=`, even though the file exists on the server, and since in `do.php` there's no special case for a page named `favicon.ico`, it defaults to the 404 error page. Other resources of the page are not affected by this, since they're under sub-directories which have no dots in their name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the fact the fact that `RewriteCond` only applies to the very next `RewriteRule`. You can have your rules like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
AddCharset UTF-8 .css
AddCharset UTF-8 .js

AddType image/svg+xml svg
ErrorDocument 404 /Hunpony/404
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Hunpony/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ do.php?do=news [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\wáéíóöőúüű.]+|-?\d+)(?:\/((?:[\wáéíóöőúüű]+|-?\d+)(?:\/(?:[\wáéíóöőúüű]+|-?\d+))?))?\/?$ do.php?do=$1&data=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```